# Got "Run-time error '31602'" when running DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport

Tags: ms-access-2010

Try to create an one-click button to import multiple tables from Oracle.  Following is the code behind the On Click event of the button (with one table for now):

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='FCR_LABOR_COST_SUMMARY1'")) Then
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "FCR_LABOR_COST_SUMMARY1"
End If

DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport ("Import-FCR_LABOR_COST_SUMMARY1")

End Sub
```

Encountered the an error "Run-time '31602': The specification with the specified index does not exist.  Specify a different index. 'Import-FCR_LABOR_COST_SUMMARY1'." when running "DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport"

The source table does not have any index on it. No need to have any index on the target table.  Look like Access is trying to enforce an index on the target table.  Is there anyway to turn this off? I'm new to Access and VB, please provide advice and directions on how to resolve this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To save a specication follow [this document](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/save-the-details-of-an-import-or-export-operation-as-a-specification-6b94e183-2b10-4333-a31a-001fe75321b5):

Create an import or export specification

```
1. Start the import or export operation from Access.

2. The import and export wizards are available on the External Data tab. The import wizards are in the Import & Link group, and the export wizards are in the Export group.

3. Follow the instructions in the wizard. After you click OK or Finish, and if Access successfully completes the operation, the Save Import Steps or Save Export Steps page appears in the wizard.

4. On the wizard page, click Save import steps or Save export steps to save the details of the operation as a specification.

5. Access displays an additional set of controls. This figure shows the dialog box with those controls available.

6. The Save Import Steps dialog box

   In the Save as box, type a name for the specification.
   In the Description box, type a description to help you or other users identify the operation at a later time.

7. To create an Outlook task that reminds you when it is time to repeat this operation, click Create Outlook Task.

8. Click Save Import or Save Export to save the specification. Access creates and stores the specification in the current database.

9. If you clicked Create Outlook Task on either the Save Import Steps or Save Export Steps page of the wizard, an Outlook Task window appears. Fill in the details of the task and then click Save & Close.
```

If the saved import or export specification you choose for the *Saved Import Export Name* argument is deleted after the macro is created, Access displays the following error message when the macro is run:

> The specification with the specified index does not exist. Specify a different index. 'specification name'.

From: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/runsavedimportexport-macro-action-41c366d8-524e-4c7e-847d-c2cf7abb2049